# Applying CSS to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code. How do I set a different CSS style on each of the outcomes - correct & incorrect.

The CSS styles are wordglow1 and wordglow2...

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            alert('Correct');
        } else {
            alert(guesses[word].join('') + ' is the incorrect spelling. The word is spelt - ' + word)
        }

        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').droppable('disable');
        }
    }
});
```

These are the class's I need to assign to the conditions...

```
<div id="rightanswer" class="wordglow2"></div>
<div id="wronganswer" class="wordglow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.addClass is your friend

```
$(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $(selector).addClass('corrent');
            alert('Correct');
        } else {
            alert('Incorrect');
            $(selector).addClass('wrong spelling')
       }

            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').droppable('disable');
            }    
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would the name of the CSS style go? @Jamie Hutber

Comment: sorry, thats my misstake. $(selector).addClass('corrent') 'corrent' being the class that you would like to had added. You might also want to use removeClass once everything is ok

Comment: Really sorry but this still doesn't work I want to add a style to correct and a style to incorrect, not remove the alert.

Comment: no worries, i'll update the code but, this `$(selector)` is an example and you should edit the selector to where ever you want to add the class to. I cannot know what markup you want to add the class to

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add a CSS class ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)) to the relevant element, and style those classes as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");
            alert('Correct');
        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow");
            alert('Incorrect');
        }
    }
}
});
```